# POST endpoint not getting permitted even added to the filterchain

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have created an Spring Boot application with Spring security and hit on an issue related to filter-chain.

Here is the **filter-chain**:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthFilter authFilter;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserInfoService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/user", "/api/auth/generateToken").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/user/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/admin/**").authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(sessionConfigure -> sessionConfigure.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}
```

I also have added a **CORS config** as well to support React frontend.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigure() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is my **endpoint**:

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@PostMapping("/api/auth/generateToken")
    public String authenticateAndGetToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(),
                        authRequest.getPassword()));
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return jwtUtil.generateToken(authRequest.getUsername());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("invalid user request !");
        }
    }
```

Here I remove this authentication code snippet and add just a string return, it will work as expected. I am struggling with the connection between that and this. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Both Spring MVC and SPring Security have CORS support and configuration, you are using Spring Security but are configuring CORS support for Spring MVC.